# Como trabalhar com variável sensível no angular

Tags: angular

Estou com grandes problemas, tenho vários computadores onde cada um deles consome uma variável porém os dados deles são diferentes, para exemplificar:

> Tenho arquivo app.js onde há uma rota para acessar minha api, em desenvolvimento tenho um link e em produção outro, quero ficar evitando a troca constante e evitar o risco de esquecer o link em produção ou desenvolvimento.

Ja encontrei alguma ferramenta que fazia esta serviço uma `api` porém perdi aonde ela estava.

Alguem teria alguma ideia ou outra `api` para solucionar meu problema ?

Comment: Existem várias maneiras de implementar um mecanismo assim. Qual tipo de tecnologia server-side você está utilizando?

Comment: @OnoSendai na verdade preciso mesmo é para front-end. Porém no back-end utilizo Laravel

Comment: O front-end pode ser o consumidor da informação, mas eu suponho que a parte que identifica como ambiente de produção ou desenvolvimento é o servidor, correto?

Comment: Não, existem variáveis sensíveis no front-end tambêm